# Can I filter a WSDL-based SOAP query using PowerShell's New-WebServiceProxy to only send one parameter?

Tags: web-services, powershell

Problem: All web service calls to ServiceNow's ../cmdb_ci_win_server.do?WSDL table return zero results.

Cause: I'm using PowerShell's New-WebServiceProxy method, which creates a .NET .dll dynamically from the WSDL definition provided by ServiceNow. The WSDL defines 174 params of which I wish to define and query against just one, but when exercised the .dll always sends the other 173 empty params in the WHERE clause of its query, which obviously results in a non-match situation.

Hopes: The dynamic .dll lets me create a parameter object that contains the 174 params, and then lets me set properties as needed. Is it possible for me to create a similar object somehow only containing the single param I need? I've tried doing so with $param.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,$paramClassName), but the resulting param object was not acceptable to the $wsproxy.getRecords($param) call. Also, I was not able to directly add a native property, only NoteProperties. Reverting to using the original param object, is it possible for me to remove 173 of the params? The underlying object seems immutable, but maybe there's some trick I've never seen?

Demonstration code:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$wsproxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri 'https://snowtest/cmdb_ci_win_server.do?WSDL' -Credential $cred 

if ($wsproxy) {
    # Force $cred onto the new wsproxy, or it will default to non-authenticated calls
    $wsproxy.Credentials = $cred

    # The parameter object we'll send with the query must be built from the custom object. 
    # That requires we extract the class name from the method's parameter definition.  
    # All my attempts to create a custom query object failed, including forcing the classname. 
    $overloadDefinitions = $wsproxy.getRecords.OverloadDefinitions
    $paramClassName = $overloadDefinitions[0] -ireplace '^[^(]+\(([^ ]+).+$', '$1'
    $param = New-Object $paramClassName
    $param.host_name = 'ServerName'
    $wsproxy.getRecords($param)
}
```

Comment: I may answer this question later. I've got a buddy looking for a possible third way. My solution at present is to use the code behind the New-WebServiceProxy method (it's available out there somewhere. If I answer, I'll link it) and intercept the pre-compiled WSDL-based source code. I modify the query method by removing all properties from it except the one I intend to query, then compile that source into an assembly and use it normally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is applicable to what you are asking or not, but I wasn't able to successfully interact with the ServiceNow web services until I followed these instructions.

https://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Microsoft_.NET_Web_Services_Client_Examples

Basically you are generating a .NET web client, you need to uncheck the box specified in the requirements in that URL.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate the thought. I may be able to make use of it. Since I'm using PowerShell instead of Visual Studio, I don't have the checkbox you reference, but I may be able to do the same thing somehow with direct property access. Basically, right now I'm forced to use URL connections for everything, instead of web services. In my proofs of concept, I was able to successfully connect using the method I mention above - intercept the code and alter it prior to letting it compile - but my org is not ready to support web service connectivity.

Comment: The check box is a configuration on the ServiceNow instance itself.  As an administrator it's under System Properties --> Web Services.  If your organization isn't supporting web services this might not be a viable option for you though.

Comment: Ah. I didn't understand that. Thank you. I'll keep this in mind if they unlock the door for us!